# iFrame link to load in Parent page without specific href alteration

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, iframe, navigation

UPDATED:

Is there any javascript I can include that results in any link selected within an iFrame to load in the parent page on SharePoint 2007? I am using a content editor web part.

This is the code I am currently using. I have my iFrame displaying a specific section of the target page. I got this code from http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108520

```
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    #container{
        width:700px;
        height:300px;
        border:1px solid #000; 
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:auto;
    }
    #container iframe {
        width:720px;
        height:605px;
        margin-left:-20px;
        margin-top:-305px;   
        border:0 solid;
    }        
    -->
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="container">
    <iframe src="my URL" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

I have replaced my actual URL with "my URL".

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Karl

Answer (score 0):

you don't need javascript to change the target of a link on html 4 transitional or html 5, that's what the target attribute is for

if you want the link to replace the parent page completely, simply set the target attribute of the `<a>` to `target="_top"`

[special values for the target attribute - html recomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/types.html#h-6.16)

if you want to change the content of another iframe in the parent page, you set the target value to the name attribute of the other frame

[changing frame content - html recomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/present/frames.html#adef-target)

you can also set the target attribute on a form element

Comment: Hi Einacio, thanks for the reply. I neglected to mention in my original post that I am try to achieve this in SharePoint (I have noe edited my post). I tried your remedy and it did not fix my problem. It must be a problem specific to SharePoint (surprise surprise). Thanks anyway though.